# How to run Emacs nnrss-* commands

Tags: emacs

Specifically, I want to run `nnrss-opml-import` command, which should import [an OPML file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML). Trying to run the command with `M-x nnrss-opml-import` tells me the command doesn't exist. I want to experience reading RSS feeds from Emacs.

This is Debian, running Emacs 24.

Comment: Do you have autoloads in place, and/or have you started Gnus?

Comment: Do I start Gnus with `M-x gnus`? If so, I did and still no luck. I have also tried to load it with `M-x load-library` and still no luck. Will have to read some doc on autoloading.

Comment: See the intro at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusRss